# How to add class within a fixed range with jquery

Tags: jquery

I wish to add e.g 3 color CSS classes to a long list  tag repeatedly with jquery. I wonder how to implement this. Still figuring out....

Before:

```
<div class="mylist">
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 1</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 2</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 3</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 4</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 5</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 6</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 7</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 8</a></div>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div class="mylist">
  <div class="item"><a href="#" class="color1">record 1</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#" class="color2">record 2</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#" class="color3">record 3</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#" class="color1">record 4</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#" class="color2">record 5</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#" class="color3">record 6</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#" class="color1">record 7</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#" class="color2">record 8</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `jquery`,

```
$('div.item a').each(function(index){
    $(this).addClass('color'+(index%3+1));
});
```

```js
    $('div.item a').each(function(index){
        $(this).addClass('color'+(index%3+1));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mylist">
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 1</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 2</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 3</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 4</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 5</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 6</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 7</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 8</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need jQuery when you can do this with CSS and [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)?

```css
.item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color:red;
}
.item:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background-color:green;
}
.item:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mylist">
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 1</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 2</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 3</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 4</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 5</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 6</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 7</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">record 8</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is simple and great no doubt, but I need to cater for the old browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
var i=1;
$('div.item a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('class','color'+i)
    if(i==3){
      i=0; 
    }
    i++;
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/55bh503m/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var tempVar = 1;
$('.mylist.item').each(function(){
   if( tempVar > 3 )
      tempVar = 1;
   $( this ).find( "a" ).addClass( "color"+tempVar );
   tempVar++;
});
```